# Failed test expectation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a carts controller in my app

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    @products = @cart.products
  end
end
```

and wrote test cartscontroller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe CartsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    let(:cart_full_of){ create(:cart_with_products, products_count: 3)}
    before do
      get :show
    end
    it { expect(response.status).to eq(200) }
    it { expect(response.headers["Content-Type"]).to eql("text/html; charset=utf-8")}
    it { is_expected.to render_template :show }
    it 'should be products in current cart' do
      expect(assigns(:products)).to eq(cart_full_of.products)
    end
  end
end
```

My factories.rb looks such:

```
factory(:cart) do |f|
  f.factory(:cart_with_products) do
    transient do
      products_count 5
    end
    after(:create) do |cart, evaluator|
      create_list(:product, evaluator.products_count, carts: [cart])
    end
  end
end

factory(:product) do |f|
  f.name('__product__')
  f.description('__well-description__')
  f.price(100500)
end
```

but I have got an error:

```
FCartsController GET #show should be products in current cart
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:products)).to eq(cart_full_of.products)

   expected: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Product id: 41, name: "MyProduct", description: "Pro...dDescription", price: 111.0, created_at: "2016-11-24 11:18:43", updated_at: "2016-11-24 11:18:43">]>
        got: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Looks like  I have no created products at all because of empty product model array ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [], simultaneously, I investigate product`s id is increasing with every test attempt.At the moment I have no solid ideas that is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` of the created `cart` is not assigned to the session of your `get :show`.

```
before do
  session[:cart_id] = cart_full_of.id
  get :show
end

# or

before do
  get :show, session: { cart_id: cart_full_of.id }
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Your `find` in the controller need the `session[:cart_id]` value, but your test didn't provide this data to the controller request. If you use one of the codes above the test request provides the session to the controller.

Comment: Great!I have rewrited  get :show , session: { cart_id: cart_full_of.id }
and it fired, but can you little explain why does your sugession work?